# QPainter composition mode example does not work as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm stuck with the difference from the book example and my version of it.
Qt version 5.12.0

As it's shown in the example:

[image]

As I see from my output:

[image]

First, destination and source In/Atop modes have not the same pictures. And, another noticed thing is, that we can see the rectangle as an additional layer between two.

Code to create the label:

```
QLabel* lblCreate(const QPainter::CompositionMode& mode){
    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel;
    lbl->setFixedSize(100, 100);

    QRect rect(lbl->contentsRect());
    QPainter painter;
    // create first image
    QImage sourceImage(rect.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    painter.begin(&sourceImage);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0));
    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
    // draw triangle
    painter.drawPolygon(QPolygon() << rect.bottomLeft()
                                   << QPoint(rect.center().x(), 0)
                                   << rect.bottomRight());
    painter.end();
    // create second image
    QImage resultImage(rect.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    painter.begin(&resultImage);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 255, 0), 4));
    painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0));
    // draw circle
    painter.drawEllipse(rect);
    painter.setCompositionMode(mode);
    painter.drawImage(rect, sourceImage);
   painter.end();

    lbl->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(resultImage));
    return lbl;}
```

How it creates in main.cpp:

```
innerLayout_2->addWidget(lblCreate(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source), 0, 0);
innerLayout_2->addWidget(new QLabel("<CENTER>Source</CENTER>"), 1, 0);
```

My own suspicion is it may be depend on `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied`.
Or it's mine handmade bug.

Anyway, I would be grateful for any ideas.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: What about the Alpha Channel of your pictures. Is there one?

Comment: try  `lbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel{ background-color: transparent;}");`

Comment: Uh, you're compositing a `QImage` with unitialized data on another `QImage` with uninitialized data. That won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composition mode works on transparent backgrounds, in your case it is not, so you must set it before painting, for this you could use the [fill()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fill-2) method:

```cpp
QImage sourceImage(rect.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
sourceImage.fill(Qt::transparent);

QImage resultImage(rect.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
resultImage.fill(Qt::transparent);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's work for me. Could you explain shortly, if the background of QImage is not transparent, what is the default color for it? For me, is actually not clear, what is the main cause, why we need to use fill() method here.

Comment: @Anton read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-1): *... Warning: This will create a QImage with uninitialized data. Call fill() to fill the image with an appropriate pixel value before drawing onto it with QPainter. ...*